# Excel: How to create a chart that automatically scales the axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I have 2 columns with values, say A and B which values I want to use as X and Y axes values correspondingly.

The values are the following:

A: 412 684 944 2009 9601

B: 7813,4 10377,6 11138,8 16216 606090

When I do it with help of wizard: Insert->2D chart->Right Mouse Click->Select Data after the data is selected it shows me the following chart that is not unfortunately scaled by X axis:
[image]

Is there some way how I can automatically scale the X axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that, you must select the chart type as `Scatter > Scatter with Straight Lines and Markers`. Then your graph becomes this:

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is also fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

The very first solution is to change the axis type: Double click on the axis->Axis options->Axis Type: Date Axis.

Comment: This won't help. Just try it.

Comment: This helps, I have tried :-)

Comment: Well, how does Excel interpret these numbers when you format them as date?: 412, 684, 944, 2009, 9601.

Comment: Nobody prohibits Excel to interpret the numbers as milliseconds